# Remove cached domain / pages from Google

Tags: seo, googlebot, noindex, google-cache, noarchive

The website's domain I work for is https://www.utazzitthon.hu and there is an other company in partnership with us, they have a domain that is directing to our server and our content, but with this domain http://szallas.kutyabarat.hu. Only 3 type of pages should be seen under that domain, all the other should not appear in Google.

Maybe in the beginning the **noindex** wasn't set everywhere and 3000+ pages were cached in Google. site:szallas.kutyabarat.hu

Do you have any idea how could I remove them as soon as possible so it wouldn't weaken our main domain as a matter of SEO factor?

I changed the meta to this now:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="noindex, nofollow, noarchive, nosnippet">
```

Is the only way waiting for Google to crawl the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to wait; you can actively ask Google (and Bing, separately) to come re-crawl the site.

You would have to have access to the other site's Google Search Console, and that site would have to be verified in GSC. Then in the partner site, generate an XML sitemap with only the pages you want indexed. Check that site's robots.txt to ensure that you are not blocking search engines from the pages you want re-crawled and noindexed. (If you block the pages, the crawlers won't crawl the URL's and see your new meta tags.) Then go back to GSC and resubmit the new sitemap. As the site is re-crawled, search engines will take note of your new directives.

That said, it can take search engines a while to drop the content out of the index. Some of the content may be taken out right away, some may be suppressed deep into SERPs first and then taken out. Unfortunately, sometimes it's a process. After performing the above steps, if you still see your noindexed nofolowed content in SERPs, you can request that those URL's be manually (temporarily) removed through Google Search Console's "Remove URL's" section. (But let them crawl the site before you do this.)

A word on your new meta tags. Since you've set those tags to noindex, nofollow already, setting noarchive and nosnippet is redundant, because the first two make the page virtually invisible to search engines, and are thus sufficient.

One final bit of advice, have a chat with the partner site's server admins re: why the site is redirecting to yours. I've seen a host of SEO issues stemming from these kinds of setups. If there's no good reason why that site links to or redirects to your content with pages that shouldn't be indexed, you may want to discuss additional actions they could take, and ways to avoid this sort of thing in the future.

Comment: Thank you Henry! I'll do my best to follow your advice. Well, we have a search page within our system where you can find hotel rooms and book them. This other site has a special kind of hotel database, but no booking system, so they're using ours. Their domain directs to our search page with a different look and setup, also to our hotel and package pages. So only these 3 types of pages should appear on Google or if I think it through neither of them actually. Nothing should've been indexed from this domain.

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for the extra clarity on this one. I think after you take the steps above and see the domain drop sufficiently deep into the SERPs, or drop out almost completely, you can use your robots.txt to disallow all bots from crawling all content. Good luck!